# Pandas turn a repeat column 2 into a header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    df =
         **col1**     **col2**          **col3**

         date1        variant1         value
         date1        variant2         value
         ...          ...               ...
         date2        variant1         value
         date2        variant2         value
         ...           ...               ...
         date_n       variant1         value
         date_n       variant2         value
```

I want to convert this into:

```
        **date**    **variant1**         **variant2**        ...

        date1        value                value             ...
        date2        value                value              ...
        ...          ...                  ...
        date_n       value                value              ...
```

Column headers are highlighted in both the cases. Value can be different in different cells and is a float number. How to do this?

Minimum Working Example

```
      col1            col2        col3
      16-05-2021      variant1    0.02
      16-05-2021      variant2    0.05
      17-05-2021      variant1    0.08
      17-05-2021      variant2    0.03
      18-05-2021      variant1    0.01
      18-05-2021      variant2    0.00
```

Desired:

```
     Date            Variant1             Variant2
     16-05-2021       0.02                 0.05
     17-05-2021       0.08                 0.03
     18-05-2021       0.01                 0.00
```

Comment: You can pivot your DataFrame: `df.pivot(index="col1",columns="col2",values="col3")`

Comment: It does, I did not know this existed. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped